# Retrieving Mailbox Rights from AD using System.DirectoryServices

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, active-directory

I need to pull back the security descriptors for the active directory attribute "msExchMailboxSecurityDescriptor" on user account objects.

So far, all I can find is that I need to [use this class to do so](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectorysecurity%28v=VS.80%29.aspx), but I cannot find any example code of how to start to pull what I want out using it.

I'm restricted to using .Net v2.0.

Anyone with any experience or ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the ActiveDS COM component, it seems much simpler:

```
Imports ActiveDS

Private Function GetSecurityDescriptor(ByVal DNPath As String) As List(Of AccessControlEntry)

        Dim AceList As New List(Of AccessControlEntry)

        Try

            Dim ent As New DirectoryEntry(String.Format("LDAP://{0}", DNPath))
            Dim sd As SecurityDescriptor = CType(ent.Properties("msExchMailboxSecurityDescriptor").Value, SecurityDescriptor)
            Dim acl As AccessControlList = CType(sd.DiscretionaryAcl, AccessControlList)
            Dim ace As AccessControlEntry

            For Each ace In CType(acl, IEnumerable)

                AceList.Add(ace)

            Next

        Catch ex As Exception

            Return AceList

        End Try

        Return AceList

    End Function
```